# IOS Disable "Bluetooth pairing request" popup

Tags: ios, bluetooth

When I connect to a BLE device, "Bluetooth Pairing Request" popup will be shown. If pressing yes, the device will be added into "My Devices" in Bluetooth Settings.
Is there any way that "Bluetooth Pairing Request" popup is not shown?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to avoid that pop up. It is exactly like the push notification popup. It is triggered by iOS and there is no way to override it using the non-private APIs provided by Apple.

Comment: In case of other app (ex. iTracing in Appstore), this popup is not shown after making a connection.

Comment: I'm using CBCentralManager and CBPeripheral for BLE.

Comment: The other app may be using the Multipeer connectivity framework and not core bluetooth.

Comment: I don't think so. The "iTracing" is an app for connecting to iTag (BLE device). Is it possible to connect it using Multipeer connectivity?

Comment: I'm a 100% sure it is possible to prevent it, but only on the Bluetooth device itself, so only if you own the (code of the) Bluetooth device and do some low low-level programming. I don't think it's possible to prevent it in your app code.